# Import a GitHub repo into Databricks community edition

Tags: apache-spark, github, databricks

I am trying to import some data from a public repo in GitHub so that to use it from my Databricks notebooks.

So far I tried to connect my Databricks account with my GitHub as described [here](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/github-version-control.html), without results though since it seems that GitHub support comes with some non-community licensing. I get the following message when I try to set the GitHub token which is required for the GitHub integration:

[image]

The same [question](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/16899/import-a-repository-from-githubimport-a-repository.html) has been asked before on the official Databricks forum.

What is the best way to import and store a GitHub repo on databricks community edition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this using `shell` commands from the notebook itself. To retrieve the repository for the 1st time I did `git clone` via HTTPS:

```sh
%sh git clone https://github.com/SomeDataRepo/TheData.git --depth 1 --branch=master /dbfs/FileStore/TheData/
```

Why not SSH? Well SSH requires to setup the SSH keys which was not necessary in my case.

Finally, every time that I need a fresh version of the data I execute a `git pull` before executing my program:

```sh
%sh git -C /dbfs/FileStore/TheData/ pull
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have python installed on your desktop, install the databricks cli, clone the git repo to your local, then use the workspace cli to import the entire repo as a directory.

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html

Comment: Hi and thank you, I didn't manage to do this for community edition. Databricks portal doesn't allow me to create a token required for the databricks cli. Can you confirm that it worked in your case?

Comment: so you have Azure license? I am referring only to databricks community edition here

Comment: Doesn't appear to be an option for community edition

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is, just import the .dbc file direct into your user workspace on Community Edition, as explained by Databricks here:

[Import GitHub repo into Community Edtion Workspace](https://www.databricks.training/step-by-step/importing-courseware-from-github/)

1. In GitHub, in the pane to the right, under **Releases**, click on the
   **Latest** link:
   [Latest release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcINw.png)
2. Under **Assets** look for the link to the DBC file
3. Right click the DBC file's link and copy the link location (there is
   no need to download this file)
   [.dbc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3nir.png)
4. Back in Databricks, click on the **Workspace** icon in the
   navigational pane to the left
5. In the **Workspace** swimlane, click the Home button to open your
   home folder. It should open the folder **/Users/your-email-address**
   as in **/Users/student@example.com**
6. In the swimlane for your email address, click on the down chevron
   and select **Import**
   [Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxId2.png)
7. In the **Import Notebooks** dialog

- Select **URL**
- Paste in the URL copied in step #3 above
- Click **Import**

8. Once the import is done, select the new folder for this course to
   view this course's notebooks.
9. Which notebook you should start with depends on your courseware and/or instructor.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33098383)