# Apache Spark continuously download data from single url

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

There is url which returns a CSV data. The actual data by this url updates each 10 minutes. Do I need to manually download the data by this url into the file and then load this file by Apache Spark, or for example I can point Spark to this url and Spark will automatically redownload data by this url from time to time and process it? Is it possible for example with Spark Structured Streaming?

Comment: It sounds good idea to use spark for automatic downloading. However, I think.. how effective spark for that purpose compared to another one, it would be more concern.

Comment: Do you know, how it can be technically achieved to let Spark automatically redownload the file with some frequency?

Comment: I know that Sparks Streaming is not a true streaming, so it is not suitable for low latency requirements. Do you know that Sparks Streaming is stateless by nature?

Comment: you can always make a `git pull` instead to refresh the data. I had a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078444/import-a-github-repo-into-databricks-community-edition) recently

Answer (score 1):

There is file.sreams like this example

```
val fileStreamDf = sparkSession.readStream
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(schema)
  .csv("/tmp/input") //folder where file is
```

But AFIAK.   I'm not aware of any  http url stream
I think from sources like s3 it should be possible.

If you want to explore pls see this.

[spark structured streaming via HTTP communication](https://github.com/bluejoe2008/spark-http-stream)

which uses below components.

```
kafka-clients-0.10: used by KafkaAsReceiver
httpclient-4.5: HttpStreamClient uses HttpClient project
jetty-9.0: HttpStreamServer is devploped upon Jetty
spark-2.1: spark structued streaming libray
```